# vertical-align:middle property is ignored inside a div

Tags: html, css

I have some divs that contain a number (bigger font) and a label (smaller font). 
The result I try to get is the following one:

[image]

However, there's still a big space between the numbers and the labels:

[image]

... which seems to come from the fact the text is not vertically-aligned in the middle of its parent div:

[image]

... although in the CSS of this class I say to align it in middle:

```
.boxText {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

I'm running out of ideas, can anyone please help on putting closer the numbers and the labels? You can play around [on this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/12Lz2wjc/1/) where I reproduce the issue.

Comment: Take a look at this updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/12Lz2wjc/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The height for box text deppends on his parrent

```
.summary {
  height: 75px;
}

.summaryBoxes {
  height: 55px;
}
```

This are the elements you should change so you can change the look of their children.

```css
.left-column {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  width: 33%;
}

.page {
  margin: 1.2rem;
}

.summary {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  margin-top: 1.2rem;
  margin-bottom: 1.2rem;
  width: 80%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  height: 75px;
}

.summaryBoxes {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 55px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.summaryErrors {
  border: 1px solid #4d94ff;
  color: #4d94ff;
}

.summaryRetries {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.summarySmallBoxes {
  width: 100px;
}

.summaryBoxes {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 55px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.boxText {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.counters {
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="summary">
  <div class="summaryBoxes summarySmallBoxes summaryErrors boxText">
    <div class="counters" style="height:70%;">
      5
    </div>
    <div style="height:30%;">
      errors
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="summaryBoxes summarySmallBoxes summaryErrors boxText">
    <div class="counters" style="height:70%;">
      3
    </div>
    <div style="height:30%;">
      warnings
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="summaryBoxes summarySmallBoxes summaryRetries boxText">
    <div class="counters" style="height:70%;">
      0
    </div>
    <div style="height:30%;">
      retries
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks a lot Gerardo, that's exactly what I needed.

Comment: You are welcome. Code on!

Answer (score 1):

Another way you can do it is remove the extra divs and use content in the css like:

https://jsfiddle.net/12Lz2wjc/1/

```
<div class="summary">
  <div class="summaryBoxes summarySmallBoxes summaryErrors boxText">
    <div class="counters">5</div>
  </div>
  <div class="summaryBoxes summarySmallBoxes summaryErrors boxText">
    <div class="counters">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="summaryBoxes summarySmallBoxes summaryRetries boxText">
    <div class="counters">0</div>
  </div>
</div>

.left-column {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  width: 33%;
}

.page {
  margin: 1.2rem;
}

.summary {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  margin-top: 1.2rem;
  margin-bottom: 1.2rem;
  width: 80%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  height: 105px;
}

.summaryErrors {
  border: 1px solid #4d94ff;
  color: #4d94ff;
}

.summaryRetries {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.summarySmallBoxes {
  width: 100px;
}

.summaryBoxes {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 85px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.boxText {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.counters {
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 22px auto;
  line-height: 15px;
}

.summaryBoxes:nth-child(1) .counters::after{
  content: "\A errors";
  font-size: 18px;
  white-space: pre;
}

.summaryBoxes:nth-child(2) .counters::after{
  content: "\A warnings";
  font-size: 18px;
  white-space: pre;
}

.summaryBoxes:nth-child(3) .counters::after{
  content: "\A retries";
  font-size: 18px;
  white-space: pre;
}
```